# Laurent series of matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, laurent-series

I need to find the Laurent series  of a matrix function around $z=\infty$, but I lack the math knowledge. I can't find a way to get it with `WolframAlpha` or `sympy`. The equation is simply

$$(z - \mathbf{V}(z))^{-1} $$

For a scalar $v$ `WolframAlpha` gives me the series

$$\frac{1}{z-v} = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{v}{z^2} + \mathcal{O}(z^{-3}).$$

I assume this can be obtained from the Geometric series? How do I get the generalization for matrices?

Comment: I think Neumann series can be employed... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: I see, choosing $\tilde{\mathbf{T}} = \mathbf{T}/z$ yields then the exactly same result as for a scalar. I also obtain the same result if I define my inverse as a new matrix $\mathbf{M}$ and recursively evaluate the function. Then I have to check the rest again, things don't add up for me yet.

Comment: Is $z$ a matrix? And what you mean by *applying* $V$ to $x$?

Comment: No it is no matrix, $z$ is a complex number. I do not understand what you mean with your second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user550103 gave the right hint in the comment, the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series)

$$ {(1 - \mathbf{T})}^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{T}^k$$

can be applied to abtain the expansion:

$$ 
{(z - \mathbf{V}(z))}^{-1} 
= z^{-1}{(1 - \mathbf{V}(z)/z)}^{-1} 
= z^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbf{V}^k(z)}{z^k}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbf{V}^k(z)}{z^{k+1}}.
$$